# What does the immutability check middleware do in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, middleware, store, redux-toolkit, mutation

I am trying to learn Redux Toolkit and came across the default middleware for configureStore():

According to [this page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware):

Immutability check middleware: deeply compares state values for mutations. It can detect mutations in reducers during a dispatch, and also mutations that occur between dispatches (such as in a component or a selector). When a mutation is detected, it will throw an error and indicate the key path for where the mutated value was detected in the state tree. (Forked from redux-immutable-state-invariant.)

I am confused. Aren't the reducers and dispatch function supposed to mutate state values? Why should errors ever be thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to accidentally mutate state in your component.

Imagine you have something like

```js
const myList = useSelector(state => state.foo.bar)
myList.sort()
```

that was an accidental state mutation - since `myList` is a reference to your store, and `.sort()` mutates an array instead of creating a new, sorted copy of it.

That is a bug that often goes unnoticed for a while until you get very weird an hard to debug bugs in your application.

As for reducers being allowed to mutate state: yes and no. In an immer reducer like in `createSlice`, you are allowed to write mutating logic, but under the hood it will create a new copy of the old state and never "mutate" the old state - so that is safe. But if you are hand-writing a reducer, it is very easy to do the same as above - a call to `.sort()` or `.push` and you accidentally modified the old store value.

And that middleware checks both of that: accidental mutation outside of reducers, as well as accidental mutation in hand-written ones.